# Series acceleration for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{H^k}{k!}\right)^\beta$, $\beta\ll 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, na.numerical-analysis

The probability mass of the Conway-Maxwell-Poisson variable $K$ is given by
$$
\mathsf P(K=k)=\frac{1}{Z(H,\beta)}\left(\frac{H^k}{k!}\right)^\beta
$$
where
$$
Z(H,\beta)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{H^k}{k!}\right)^\beta.
$$

The computation of $Z$ is the subject of many papers in the literature, with most of the focus on asymptotic expansions for large $H$.

For the special case $\beta\in(0,1)$, particularly $\beta\ll 1$, numerically evaluating $Z$ is especially challenging as the series expansion converges quite slowly. At exactly $\beta=1$ we of course get the closed-form $Z(H,1)=e^{H}$.

What, if any, series acceleration methods are available for numerically estimating $Z$ in the case of $\beta\ll 1$? There is no restriction of $H$ other than nonnegativity.

The first couple terms of Euler-Maclaurin expansion give a decent asymptotic approximation of the constant; however, I'm not interested in asymptotic expansions.

Comment: Have you tried Levin's u sequence transformation?. If it works for $\beta\ll 1$ and precision required $d_s$ you should use a working precision of about $1.8\,d_s$  and a minimum number of terms $N=1.1\,d_s$

Comment: If you have some known $Z(H,\beta)$ values (in high precision preferably) for the range of parameters that you are interested in, I can test if Levin's u works in these cases. I have coded this acceleration method (and others as well) in PARI-GP. I need such input to answer your request.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga I have not tried this.  I am interested in parameters $\beta\in[0.1,1]$ and $H\in(0,10]$.  I could provide sum numerical values of $Z$ using Mathematica.

Comment: I have tested some summation methods for this kind of CMP series. Non-integer powered $\Gamma(n+1)$ make them hard to be summed up. Levin's u works just on asymptotically related hypergeometric sequences and this is not the case. However some methods based on quadratures can provide excellent performance.  Algorithms either **sumnumdelta()** in H. Cohen - Numerical Recipes for Number Theory (2010) or **Sumdelta()**, a variation of Euler-MacLaurin, from K. Belabas - H. Cohen, Numerical Algorithms for Number Theory Using Pari-GP (2020) work pretty fine on these CMP series.

Comment: BTW these algorithms can be easily translated to Mathematica code.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga I did some digging after your original comment and understand the form of the transformation. But how to implement it efficiently, e.g. in Mathematica, I'm not so sure. I tried numerocally.evaluatong the sum using NSum[] but was only getting a few decimal places of precision.

Comment: @Aaron_Hendrickson, H. Cohen's **sumnumdelta()** algorithm is an acceleration method that uses a variant of Euler-MacLaurin which involves computing symmetric diﬀerences instead of derivatives. The integral part from $N$ to $\infty$ is computed using a double exponential numerical quadrature method. These values are found using single precision (about 38 decimal digits) in PARI GP. $$ Z(1,0.1)=7.6427620366886605818304606089451131454$$ $$Z(10,0.9)=10496.161071914429007921259218554843404$$ $$Z(10,0.1)=52.077597276384465805943421681943078911$$